# How to insert custom link before last menu in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, topmenu, link

I have 5 categories in main menu and want to add custom link in between menu.

How can I add this?

For example:

**Menu1  Menu2 Menu3 Menu4 Custom_Link(Static) Menu5**

Code Is:

```
<ul>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
<li class="vertical-submenu"><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('custom')?>"><?php echo __('Our story')?>

<div class="menu-dropdown">
<ul class="level0 submenu">
<li class="level1 nav-2-1 nav-1-1 first">
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('custom1')?>">
<figure><img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl('pub/media/wysiwyg/') ?>custom1.jpg" /></figure>
<span><?php echo __('custom1') ?></span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="level1 nav-2-1 nav-1-2">
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('custom2')?>">
<figure><img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl('pub/media/wysiwyg/') ?>custom2.jpg" /></figure>
<span><?php echo __('custom2') ?></span>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</li>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You can do why jquery. Is it an option?

Comment: I meant via jquery!

Comment: You can add this link if category Menu4  fixed always.

Comment: @LAW  I have done using jquery.

Comment: @VinodKumar Cool, It would be great if you share your answer here, so that others can get help!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do easily.

```
jQuery('a[href*="//www.host.com/host-collection"]').attr({onClick:"return redirectFunction1()",href:"javascript:void(0);"});

function redirectFunction1() {

 window.open("//www.host.com/[your custom link]", "_blank");

}
```

You need to create extra menu link between menu 4 and menu 5 and replace that menu link in above script.

Comment: I don't want to create category, I have added plugin to create custom link which is add in last but i want to add in between or before last menu.

Comment: You need to create menu link as you already created in admin panel.